# Optimal mortgage rate strategy

Tags: interest-rates, optimization, random-walk

When buying a mortgage, you can choose to "lock in" a rate at any point within 60 days of your closing date. Once locked in, you can't revert.

This makes it a [secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) - in the traditional problem, we would want to lock in at the lowest point after waiting $\sqrt{60}$ days. However, unlike in the traditional problem the rates are not i.i.d., so it becomes harder.

[One model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Random_Walk_Down_Wall_Street) is to assume prices form a random walk; I've found [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414988901044) whose abstract says that the optimal strategy in random walk secretary problems is to choose the first rate, but the text is behind a pay wall so I'm not sure of all  the assumptions.

Can someone point me to a reference on optimal stopping in the case of locking in mortgage rates?

Comment: Note that you can often break the lock for a fee (e.g. 1/8).